# Role management with ASP.NET inbuilt controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, roles

I am using the ASP.NET inbuilt login and role management solution (creates table like aspnet_Users etc. and gives access to MembershipUser and the such).

However, at this stage I am a bit stuck with the following:

1) I need to be able to Suspend, Unsuspend and Delete (not necessary remove from table, just disable) users from my app. Is this feature inbuilt?

2) I need to have three different user roles, where one of the roles is always assigned by default. Currently I have built an app with no roles. Is ASP.NET capable of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Membership has concepts for "Approved" and "Locked out" (after X number of failed log in attempts) for users, you can probably use those features for suspending users. 4guysfromrolla.com had a great article series on [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016204853/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050306-1.aspx) , it's worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think that's available by default, but should be fairly easy to add in.
2. Roles are supported in the default implementation.  However, you'll have to define and assign the roles yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a built-in `DeleteUser`
   method. It calls a stored procedure
   named `dbo.aspnet_Users_DeleteUser`.
   You can change that stored procedure
   to suspend a user instead of
   deleting them.
2. Similarly, there is a built-in `CreateUser` method which calls a stored procedure named `dbo.aspnet_Membership_CreateUser` which you could modify. Or, you could use the `Roles.AddUserToRole` method to set the default role when the user is created, calling it in your `CreateUser` method (which would first Membership.CreateUser)